# How to make semantic search dropdown to search in hidden content as well?

Tags: search, dropdown, semantic-ui, hidden-field

Is there a way to search from a hidden text as well? I want to search from not only dropdown item text but another hidden text content as well. I know that semantic search dropdown is normally searched in the data-value field as well. But in my case data-value is just an ID. I want to add another field to search as well.